# Finding normal probabilities with printed tables and a calculator

Tags: statistics

From a HW Pset:

> The Economic Policy Institute periodically issues reports on wages of entry level workers. The Institute reported that entry level wages for male college graduates were \$21.68 per hour and for female college graduates were \$18.80 per hour in 2011 (Economic Policy Institute website, March 30, 2012). Assume the standard deviation for male graduates is \$2.30, and for female graduates, itis $2.05. Use z-table.
>
> d.  What is the probability that a sample of 120 female graduates will provide a sample mean more than $.30 below the population mean? (Round z value in intermediate calculations to 2 decimal places.)

What I did was find the z-score for being \$0.30 below population mean. 
$z=(0.30)/2.05=0.146341.$ 
When looking up on a ztable I get $p=0.4404.$

I also use the `normalcdf` function on the calculator with `normalcdf(-1E99,18.50,18.8,2.05)`and get an incorrect answer as well.

Comment: Thanks for sharing some of your work. Are you saying you think 0.4404 is an incorrect answer? Asking for help using the calculator? If the latter, it might be helpful to know what kind of calculator. It is not exactly clear what help you are hoping for.

Comment: I am trying to find the answer. When I try to solve the answer I get .4404, but I am told that is wrong. I am looking for the formula needed to solve the problem and hopefully the answer.

Comment: 2.05 is the SD for _individual_ women. You are asked about the _sample mean of 120 women,_ which has a much different SD.